# Is is possible to setup an Ibeacon to send push notifications to a mobile independent of an installed app in iOS7?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ibeacon

Is it possible to setup an BLE 4.0 Ibeacon to send a push notification to an Apple device without having it interact with an App? E.g. send a notification with a URL link which can be opened up into e.g. the Safari browser

If Ibeacon is natively supported in Ios7 then this surely must be possible do with an Ibeacon kit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot do this without an app.  Native support just means there are native APIs for your custom app to set up things to happen (like a notification) after an ibeacon is seen.

This is true because iBeacons are fairly dumb devices that do nothing but transmit a three part identifier.  Your native code is responsible for doing everything.

Unfortunately Safari provides no JavaScript APIs for iBeacons.   If you want to launch a web page in Safari when an iBeacon is seen, you can only do so with a custom app on the phone.