# Can Ibeacons or any other motherboard be setup to do 'knock' like gestures to an Apple device?

Tags: ios7, apple-push-notifications, ibeacon

Is it possible to setup an Ibeacon or another motherboard device to utlise a 'Knock' like facility when tapped by Apple device (without having a pre-installed app) ?

E.g. 
A 'knock' will send a push notification to an Iphone. Or will open up a URL on the Iphone safari browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but all iBeacon interactions require a native app.  See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20308417/1461050

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for your reply. Is there any other way apart from Ibeacon that would utlise a NFC like 'tap' that would work for Apple devices (without the need for the user to have a pre-installed app)? I am assuming this would still need to utlise bluetooth but maybe not Ibeacon tech and could be built using Raspberry pi?

Comment: iBeacon APIs on iOS are basically a small layer on top of CoreBluetooth APIs.  But CoreBluetooth on iOS7 does nothing for the user directly -- they also require an app to take advantage of their functionality.  It sounds like you are looking for a pre-installed app on iPhones that notifiy the user when a specific Bluetooth LE device is nearby.  I am afraid this does not exist.  You simply have to write an app and get it on people's phones to do something like this.

Comment: Thanks again for your prompt reply. I am looking for something that would work 'out the box' on the iphone. From what you're saying bluetooth is not going to work unless you have a pre-installed app. IS there an alternative tech that might do the trick to enable a 'tap' gesture similar to the NFC experience? (without the customer having to download anything in advance)

Comment: Daniel, the short answer is no. Apple would have to add such a thing to the OS.